# Python init default values create linked instances of class

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, graph, init

This code is meant to create a graph implementation. However, all of the nodes "self.children" link to the same list in memory, so adding children to any of them adds it to all of them. I can not for the life of me think of why this would happen, I have made classes like this many times, and not had such an issue.

I mean, just because you define a list in the default values doesn't mean I make a list then and there, does it? This is confusing...

```
class DescisionNode(object):
    def __init__(self,data,score,childs=[]):
        self.data = data
        self.score = score
        self.parent = None
        self.children = childs
    def getTop(self):
        if self.parent == None:
            return self
        else:
            return self.parent.getTop()
    def getEnds(self):
        out = []
        if len(self.children)==0:
            return [self]
        else:
            print(self,self.children)
            for n in self.children:
                out += n.getEnds()
            return out
    def add(self, newNode):
        if newNode.parent == None:
            newNode.parent = self
        else:
            raise Exception("Parent already exists.")
        if newNode is self:
            raise Exception("self may not be child")
        self.children.append(newNode)
```

Comment: It's much easier to think about building the list forward (next node), than backwards (parent node)

Answer (score -1):

This is due to this: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

> Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called (like it is in say, Ruby). This means that if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well.

You can find some discussion here:
["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

> It comes simply from the fact that functions in Python are first-class objects, and not only a piece of code.
>   As soon as you get to think into this way, then it completely makes sense: a function is an object being evaluated on its definition; default parameters are kind of "member data" and therefore their state may change from one call to the other - exactly as in any other obje

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11124740)

Comment: Edited with excerpts. Thank you.